# Why does lag only stop after reboot?

Tags: memory, adb, ram, lag, reboot

When playing games on my phone for an hour the phone starts lagging quite a bit. Nothing I do takes away the lag except restarting the device. I have tried some memory cleaning apps on the playstore, I have tried cleaning all running apps, and I have tried apps that 'simulate' a reboot.

I also checked online and there are no adb commands that clear the RAM (I don't want to clear the game cache).

I am trying to find a way to stop my phone's lag the same way restarting it does, but there seems to be no info online at all. So what is happening when the phone is rebooting that cannot be done with software alone? If it is because the memory is being cleaned, why are there no apps that work?

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to a lot of reasons, one of the main ones being thermal limits. Once you have been playing for a while, your phone might have to throttle it's performance to maintain a temperature safe for the SoC inside. I will say however, that cluttering your phone and background processes with a lot of these "memory cleaning" apps probably isn't helpful. If you are on android, there is a built in optimization widget (on new-ish devices) that you can free up ram and storage with.

Comment: I mentioned that I used all the apps that I could find. Also, why would restarting take away the thermal throttle? Surely the temperature is the same after rebooting, it only takes 16 seconds.

Comment: Not trying to be a butthole, but are you sure its not  all in your head?